# How can I reset the dock?

Tags: macos, dock

I recently updated my computer from Mavericks to El Capitan, and I'm unable to add or remove items from the dock. If I attempt to change the dock, the computer freezes and I am unable to interact with the computer through the GUI.

The machine has multiple users, and I am the only user on this system that has this problem. I suspect that it's an issue with the way my dock is configured. Is there any way to "factory-reset" the dock? Failing that, is there any way to fix a dock that can't be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the terminal, you can try deleting your dock preferences, then restarting the dock:

```
% defaults delete com.apple.dock
% killall Dock
```

This won't affect the contents of your dock, but it will reset the preferences that you'd normally edit in the Dock panel of the System Preferences.

EDIT: Per comments below, apparently this does reset dock contents for some people, but not for others—not clear why.

Comment: You said, "_This won't affect the contents of your dock_" and this is not true!  Deleting the com.apple.dock.plist file and restarting the Dock does a full reset while not only loosing the arranged order of apps it also removes all apps that have been added. Your answer is destructive while claiming it's not!

Comment: @user3439894: It's didn't remove all apps for me when I did it. It didn't change the contents of `~/Library/Prefrences/com.apple.dock.plist` for example.

Comment: But it did fix the problem of the dock causing the computer to freeze!

Comment: @Dan, It totally reset my Dock as if the User Account was just freshly created and logged in for the first time.

Comment: @user3439894: Ah. Well, at least it's only a little bit destructive.

Comment: Apologies to anyone who lost their dock contents then. It didn't affect mine when I tried it out first (having already read elsewhere that it shouldn't), but apparently that must vary from case to case for some reason.